# Convert binary string to byte-Array in Java

Tags: java, string, binary

I have a binary string and I want to split it into chunks of length 8 and then store the corresponding
bytes in a byte-Array. For example, the string "0000000011111111" should be convertert to {-128, 127}.
So far, I wrote the following function:

```
public static byte[] splitBinary(String binaryString) throws ConversionException {

    if (binaryString.length()%8 != 0) {
        throw new ConversionException();
    }

    byte[] result = new byte[binaryString.length()/8];

    while (i < result.length) {
        result[i] = (byte) (Integer.parseInt(binaryString.substring(i, i+8), 2)-128);
        i+=8;
    }
    return result;
}
```

But this results in {-128, 0}. How can I achieve the desired functionality?

Comment: @SandeepKumar OP wrote *should be convertert to {-128, 127}*

Comment: i+=8 in for loop

Comment: Yes: the input is the string  "0000000011111111" and the output shoud be the byte array  {-128, 127}.

Comment: @Vihar No! That would result in accesing `result[8]` which is invalid.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose a different index can be used for result, but according to the question this is the index the next iteration should take
iteration 1 : 0 to 7
iteration 2 : 8 to 15 and so on

Comment: Yes, I know! But just chaning the increment part of the loop will result in an exception (as I told you)!

Comment: Why would `0000000011111111` become `{-128, 127}`? --- `00000000 11111111` is a `0` and `-1` in [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Comment: Okay, then I think I was wrong about the expected result. I thought "00000000" and "11111111" would mean the smallest and the biggest byte (-128 and 127). But how could I change the function to yield {0,-1}?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the function in the following way and now it works as expected (after correcting my expectations ;)). Thank you all!

```
public static byte[] splitBinaryStringToByteArray(String binaryString) throws ConversionException {

    if (binaryString.length()%8 != 0) {
        throw new ConversionException();
    }

    byte[] result = new byte[binaryString.length()/8];

    int i =0;int j=0;
    while (i < binaryString.length()) {
        System.out.println("Substring: " + binaryString.substring(i, i+8));
        result[j] =((byte)Integer.parseInt((binaryString.substring(i, i+8)), 2));
        j++;
        i+=8;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your splitting routine is wrong.

increasing i by 1 just moves your window one charachter to the right, not two, resulting in die Strings 00000000 and 00000001 to be read.

Comment: Thank you! I changed it in the question. But now it leads to {-128,0}.

Comment: You change your question and the downvote an answer for no longer fitting your changed question?

Comment: I did not downvote anyone! I just wanted to use your helpful comment...

Answer (score 0):

I refer to result's size, it may smaller than size of `binaryString`,
but in `binaryString.substring(i, i+8)` and `i+=8`; you use as size of `binaryString`.
So change them to `binaryString.substring(i*8, i*8+8)` and `i++`.